# Populate Table View With Object Properties?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a custom class within my `UITableViewController` which contain two properties :

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

class Continent {

    var name: String = "Country name"
    var continentCountries: NSArray = ["countries of selected continent"]
}
```

now i've created several objects and placed them in an array:

```
func setup() { 
var asia = Continent()
    asia.name = "Asia"
    asia.continentCountries = ["Afghanistan","Armenia","Azerbaijan","Bahrain"] //etc..

var africa = Continent()
africa.name = "Africa"
africa.continentCountries = ["Egypt","Sierra Leone","Sudan","South Africa"] //etc..

var northAmerica - Continent() 
northAmerica.name = "North America"
northAmerica.continentCountries = ["Canada","United States of America","Mexico"] 

let theWorld = [asia,africa,northAmerica] 

}
```

notice that i had to declare my newly created objects and my array in a " `func setup()` " method because they were not recognized as "Continent" object but as a "FirstTableViewController" object

now my goal is to populate the following table view with the first property of each object being the "name", and i used the following code:

```
let aContinent = theWorld[indexPath.row] as! Continent
cell.textLabel.text = aContinent.name
```

now the issue is, anything outside of the setup() method, the controller does not recognize, and labels "undeclared", so there is no way i can add code to any of the protocol delegates of the `TableViewController` being :

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return 3 //this is just a temporary Int
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    return cell
```

what should be corrected? how do i allow my newly created class and its objects to act in unison with the initial `UITableViewController` class so i can populate this table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a property like this,so that you can use it in delegate method

```
class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

class Continent {

    var name: String = "Country name"
    var continentCountries: NSArray = ["countries of selected continent"]
}
let theWorld:[Continent] = {
    var asia = Continent()
    asia.name = "Asia"
    asia.continentCountries = ["Afghanistan","Armenia","Azerbaijan","Bahrain"] //etc..

    var africa = Continent()
    africa.name = "Africa"
    africa.continentCountries = ["Egypt","Sierra Leone","Sudan","South Africa"] //etc..

    var northAmerica = Continent()
    northAmerica.name = "North America"
    northAmerica.continentCountries = ["Canada","United States of America","Mexico"]

     return  [asia,africa,northAmerica]
    }()
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return theWorld.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = theWorld[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: i've done it just as you have and it gives me the error of "missing return in a closure expected to return '[FirstTableViewController.Continent]'

Comment: Can you update question and post full code of your code after you add my code. I am not sure where the error is from what you said. The code runs well on my Mac as screenshot

Comment: my apologies, the declaration of one of my var's was off. this worked, thanks.

Comment: hey can i interest you in a chat?? i have one inquiry, being you were the one to answer this successfully @John Durand

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You seem kind of confused. You do not want your theWorld variable to be a local variable of your setup function. You want it to be an instance var of your FirstTableViewController class, and you want setup to be an instance method of that class. (Defined inside the braces of the class.)

Comment: thats the thing, even when i define the setup method within my class, when i go outside the class, the controller doesn't recognize any of my objects. it only recognizes them if i work within the class, which i do not want to do being i want to get to the delegates

Comment: You're being too vague with your description. What class? What controller? What do you mean "when I go outside the class?" It sounds to me like you're dealing with the normal issues of scope. Instance variables are only visible the scope of the current instance, unless you refer to the owning object, e.g. `otherObject.property`. Can you edit your question to show where your method is defined, where your variables are defined, and where "the controller doesn't recognize any of my objects"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.title.text = theWorld[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```